# Trouble compiling c gsl library from max terminal

Tags: c, macos, gcc, terminal, gsl

I have a c script

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>

int main(void)
{
    const gsl_rng_type * T;
    gsl_rng * r;
    int i;
    double a,b;
    double num;
    a=10;
    b=7.2;

    gsl_rng_env_setup();

    T=gsl_rng_default;
    r=gsl_rng_alloc (T);
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        num = gsl_ran_gamma(r,a,b);
        printf("%.8f \n",num);
    }


    gsl_rng_free(r);
    return 0;
}
```

Which I have successfully compiled on a linux machine. I want to use the gsl library for other applications on my mac. So I first installed gsl using homebrew which seemed to be successful. To make sure everything was working right I tried to compile and run this script as follows

```
[ACC-259-imac:GDSC Gene Expression Modeling jmannhei$ gcc -Wall gamma.c -o gamma.out -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

which resulted in the following output

```
gamma.c:5:10: fatal error: 'gsl/gsl_rng.h' file not found
#include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

Which is exactly how I compiled it on Linux so I am not sure what is awry as I have compile c scripts in the past using this format from terminal on a mac before. My guess is it is not linking properly but I am not sure what I need to do to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find your header file directory with `brew list gsl` or `locate gsl/gsl_rng.h` then tell your compiler where the headers are. I would need the following, for example,

```
gcc -Wall -I/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/1.16/include/ gamma.c -o gamma.out -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas
```

Comment: So I got the following errord: library not found for                                                 -lgsl
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Tell your compiler where your libraries are... `brew list gsl` then append the library directory to your link line `-L/usr/local/Cellar/gsl/1.16/lib/`